# UIPickerView: difference between didSelectRow method and Value Changed event-handler method

Tags: objective-c

For UIPickerView, I see there are 2 approaches to use to determine a selected row info in a picker view component. One approach is use custom method for the Value Changed event like

```
- (IBAction)onValueChanged:(id)sender
```

The other is use a delegate method like

```
(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {...}
```

So, what is the difference between the 2 approaches? And when do I use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `UIPickerview` delegate method for change.
Since it will stop at any position and

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

method will be called, so if user exits before picker stops animating/rolling...
the method that hides the `UIPickerView` must call the uipicker for the last selected value while rolling/animating.